# Entity Framework Caching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, unity-container

I have a project that is using Entity Framework 4.1. The model has been modeled from a database on a SQL Server 2008 R2 machine.

I have a table that has 3 nvarchar columns, 2 bitcolumns, and 1 datetime column.

The application is using a repository pattern and dependency injection.  All the items in the DI container are set to Transient, except for the context which is set to Hierarchical.

Now, when I run a lambda query against the model in entity framework, it pulls my data as expected.  For example:

```
 var someData = _dataRepository.Get(data => data.Name == name && data.IsEnabled);
```

Basically the Get method of the repository is a wrapper for a .Where(filter) linq expression.

*So the issue is this:*

When I update the database (either via SMS or within code using .SaveChanges) to the bit column or the datetime column in the database and I re-query the data, the returned query data is returning what is expected.  However, whenever I update (SMS/.SaveChanges) on one of the nvarchar columns and re-query, it returns the "old" data the nvarchar use to contain from previous query -- not the updated data.

Does Entity Framework have some inherit caching that is causing this to happen?

Comment: When you say update, do you mean committing the changes as well?

Comment: try to place the table on designer again

Comment: Yes, committed.  Updated question to better explain.

Comment: I think you are holding on to some reference to a string object somewhere. The value types are updated allright,the possible reference types are not.